# Getting XML namespace with prefix

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my XML code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/".....>
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <p297:wsvitaneteResponse xmlns:p297="http://names-space.fr">
      <wsvitaneteReturn>
        <o_ERREUR />
        <o_TARIFS>
          <TARIFV1>115.49</TARIFV1>
          <TARIFV1A>123.49</TARIFV1A>
          <TARIFV1B>123.49</TARIFV1B>
          <TARIFV1AB>131.49</TARIFV1AB>
          <TARIFV2>144.05</TARIFV2>
          <TARIFV2A>152.05</TARIFV2A>
          <TARIFV2B>152.05</TARIFV2B>
          <TARIFV2AB>160.05</TARIFV2AB>
        </o_TARIFS>
      </wsvitaneteReturn>
    </p297:wsvitaneteResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Hou can I get this **TARIFV1** from this XML? This is the code C#:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(Session["xmlrs" + z + ""].ToString());
XNamespace foobar = "http://names-space.fr";
var TARIF = doc.Descendants(foobar + "TARIFV1").Select(
                            x => new { TARIFV1 = (string)x }).ToList();
```

I must add something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use this code:

```
var TARIF = doc.Descendants("TARIFV1").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```